# Is there a way to directly pass a dictionary to a library

Tags: python, robotframework

Using the Robot Framework, I know it is possible to pass a dictionary to a function like follows:

```
*** Settings ***
Library             Collections
Library             SomeLibrary

*** Variables ***
&{Dict1}     key1=value1

*** Test Cases ***
    
Testcase 1
    SomeLibrary.SomeFunction  ${Dict1}
```

But is it possible to pass a dictionary to `SomeLibrary.SomeFunction` without declaring a variable? The following code is just for visualisation:

```
*** Settings ***
Library             Collections
Library             SomeLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
    
Testcase 1
    SomeLibrary.SomeFunction  &{key1=value1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with robotframework 3.2 you can use [inline python evaluation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id117), which allows you to put any python code you want inside `${{` and `}}`:

```
SomeLibrary.SomeFunction  ${{ {'key1': 'value1'} }}
```